# I am making notes application using for input I am using tinymce and Firebase. The problem is I cannot retrieve data on tinymce textarea to edit

Tags: javascript, forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tinymce

I am making notes application using for input I am using tinymce and for database I am using Firebase. I can save data to firebase but the problem is I cannot retrieve data on tinymce textarea to edit. If I use the default textarea I am able to retrieve but then the text is not rich.
**Database part js**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
        var uid = user.uid;
        var reviewForm = document.getElementById('reviewForm');
        var fullName = document.getElementById('fullName');
        var message = document.getElementById('message');
        var hiddenId = document.getElementById('hiddenId');
        reviewForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!fullName.value || !message.value) return null
            var id = hiddenId.value || Date.now()
            db.ref(uid + '/notes/' + id).set({
                fullName: fullName.value,
                message: message.value
            });
            fullName.value = '';
            message.value = '';
            hiddenId.value = '';
        });
        // READ REVEIWS
        var x = document.createElement("HR");
        var reviews = document.getElementById('reviews');
        var reviewsRef = db.ref(uid + '/notes/');
        reviewsRef.on('child_added', (data) => {
            var li = document.createElement('li')
            li.id = data.key;
            li.innerHTML = reviewTemplate(data.val())
            reviews.appendChild(li);
        });
        reviewsRef.on('child_changed', (data) => {
            var reviewNode = document.getElementById(data.key);
            reviewNode.innerHTML = reviewTemplate(data.val());
        });
        reviewsRef.on('child_removed', (data) => {
            var reviewNode = document.getElementById(data.key);
            reviewNode.parentNode.removeChild(reviewNode);
        });
        reviews.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            var reviewNode = e.target.parentNode
            // UPDATE REVEIW
            if (e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
                fullName.value = reviewNode.querySelector('.fullName').innerText;
                message.value = reviewNode.querySelector('.message').innerText;
                hiddenId.value = reviewNode.id;
            }
            // DELETE REVEIW
            if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
                var id = reviewNode.id;
                db.ref(uid + '/notes/' + id).remove();
            }
        });
        function reviewTemplate({ fullName, message }) {
            return `
                <div class='fullName' style="font-size: 12px;  color: black; font-weight: bold; background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0); overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 1; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">${fullName}</div>
                <div class='message' style=" font-size: 12px; color: #111111; background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0); overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">${message}</div>
                <button class='delete' style="width: 50px; color: white; background-color: #aa3343; border: 0; font-size: 13px;">Delete</button>
                <button class='edit' style="width: 50px; color: black; background-color: #5a83da; border: 0; font-size: 13px;">Edit</button>
                <hr>
            `
        };
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<script>
      tinymce.init({
        selector: '#message'
      });
    </script>
<form id='reviewForm' style="background-color: #EAEAEA">
          <input type="hidden" id='hiddenId' />
          <input type="text" id='fullName' placeholder="Add Title" style="background-color: #EAEAEA; "/>
          <br/>
          <textarea id='message' placeholder="Add Content" style="background-color: #EAEAEA;"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <button id="sbutton" type='submit' style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);  height:50px; align-self: center;">Save</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>**
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE works by replacing the standard `<textarea>` HTML element with an `<iframe>` containing the Tiny editor.  That means code like:

```
var message = document.getElementById('message');
```

...will not find data in TinyMCE. Rather, it will find the original, hidden (and empty) `<textarea>`.

To get data from TinyMCE:

If the `<form>` containing TinyMCE is submitted, Tiny's content is `POST`-ed just like any HTML form. Additionally, content can be retrieved from TinyMCE with the `.getContent()` method. This will return an HTML string containing Tiny's content:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent